# Change size of elements after change language

Tags: android, resize, drawable, idioms

I have a problem when I change the language of the APP in ZTE Blade Flex (720 x 1280 299ppp).

When you start the APP, all the sizes all well:
[image]

It seems that take the image (black border) from drawable-sw280-720x1280 folder that I have made for this size. The size of text is taken from values-sw280-720x1280 folder.

After select English language option in the APP, it seems that take the image from drawable-sw299dp-720x1280 (Is the same name image but in yellow color) and the values from values-sw280-720x1280 folder:
[image]

The problem is when I select spanish language again. As you can see, It seems that takes image from drawable-sw280-720x1280 folder, as the first case, but the size of text is smaller:
[image]

I have tried the following:

1- Having just one folder for drawable and values.

2- Create a folder sw-299-720x1280 for drawable and values.

3- Create a folder sw-280-720x1280 for drawable and values.

4- Create a folder hdpi and xhdpi for drawable and values. When I try that, first time the APP takes the image from xhdpi and after change to english language it takes the image from hdpi.

Finally, to change the language I am doing that:

```
    final Configuration config = new Configuration();
     if (checkedId == R.id.idRbIdiomaEn) {
                        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH; 
                    } else if (checkedId == R.id.idRbIdiomaEs) {
                        config.locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
                    }
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    dialog.dismiss();
    startActivity(i);
    getActivity().finish();
```

-I have checked that the error only appears in Android Lollipop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution. The problem was that the APP introduced a new scale after change idiom. The soultions is:

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.fontScale=(float) 1; //0.85 small size, 1 normal size, 1,15 big etc

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```